# Who was the Blessed Virgin Mary's guardian angel?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, angels, guardian-angels

Catholic teaching is that "Every one of the faithful has his own special guardian angel from baptism. (*Sent. certa.*)" ([Ludwig Ott](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7262) II ch. 3 §30.2; cf. [Matt 18:10](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=18&l=10-#x): "See that you despise not one of these little ones: for I say to you, that their angels in heaven always see the face of my Father who is in heaven.").

According to Catholic theologians or mystics, who was the Blessed Virgin Mary's guardian angel? St. Gabriel the Archangel?

Comment: The Blessed Virgin Mary is superior to all the Heavenly Host including all the fallen angels is an approved Magisterial Teachings of the Catholic Church. How can this question be a valid Catholic question?

Comment: Mary is superior by order of grace, not nature - angels are superior to Mary according to nature, and thus would have been afforded her as everyone else, as guardian.

Comment: Mary is superior in all its forms because Mary is the Masterpiece of God, at Mary's command all the Heavenly Host must follow. Mary is created above all the creatures in Heaven and in the earth. It is evident when Archangel Gabriel the one nearest to the Throne of God bow down to Her. In the Eyes of God, Mary is superior to all creatures. She is the Sovereign Queen of All Angels.

Comment: @jongricafort it's a valid question because questions seek to gain information which we do not possess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

St. Bernard (Epistle 77 quoted in [this manual](https://archive.org/details/tractatusdebeati00card/page/230)) thought that it was St. Gabriel. I've seen this reference cited in other places, so it's genuine, but I'm struggling to find an original version of this epistle.

> Virgo Gabrieli archangelo servanda ab initio tradita fuisse credenda est.
>
> Gabriel the Archangel is believed to have delivered to serve the Virgin from the beginning

Francisco Suarez ([De Angelis, l.6, c.17, #24](https://archive.org/details/rpfranciscisuare02suar/page/754/)) records another opinion, that Mary had two guardian angels, but does not give their names.

> beatissima Virgine... habuerit duos Angelos custodes, unum ut privata persona, alium ut mater Dei, et quamdiu officium matris exercuit
>
> The Blessed Virgin had two guardian angels, one for the private person; another for [her as] the mother of God, as long as she exercised the office of mother.

Comment: I figured Suárez would've discussed it. His _De angelis_ is a very large treatise.

Answer (score -1):

**Who was the Blessed Virgin Mary's guardian angel?**

Being the Queen of Angels, Mary certainly had many Guardian Angels, probably including St. Gabriel and St. Micheal.

Mary is superior by order of grace, not nature - angels are superior to Mary according to nature, and thus would have been afforded her as everyone else, as guardian.

Mary, Queen of Angels was born like all mankind in the physical sense of the word. By a singular gift from God She was preserved from all stain of original sin at the moment of conception. St. Thomas says that all men receive a Guardian Angel at birth. Mary is no exception and received her Guardian Angel(s) as is the condition of living here on earth.

> As Origen observes (Tract. v, super Matt.) there are two opinions on this matter. For some have held that the angel guardian is appointed at the time of baptism, others, that he is appointed at the time of birth. The latter opinion Jerome approves (vide A, 4), and with reason. For those benefits which are conferred by God on man as a Christian, begin with his baptism; such as receiving the Eucharist, and the like. But those which are conferred by God on man as a rational being, are bestowed on him at his birth, for then it is that he receives that nature. Among the latter benefits we must count the guardianship of angels, as we have said above (Articles 1 and 4). Wherefore from the very moment of his birth man has an angel guardian appointed to him. - [Article 5. Whether an angel is appointed to guard a man from his birth?](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1113.htm)

Although privileged with the grace of an Immaculate Conception, Mary still had to work towards her own salvation, albeit in an exceptional manner.

> Maria Agreda, the visionary, taught that the Blessed Virgin Mary had hundreds of guardian angels, including St Michael and St Gabriel. - [Here are 7 Interesting Facts about Guardian Angels](https://Here%20are%207%20Interesting%20Facts%20about%20Guardian%20Angels)

The Venerable Mary of Agreda [The Mystical City of God](https://www.ecatholic2000.com/agreda/mystical/city.shtml#__RefHeading___Toc338962772) states the following:

> It was ordained therefore by the Most High, that the sovereign Child should voluntarily keep this silence during the time in which ordinarily other children are unable to speak. **The only exception made was in regard to the conversation held with the angels of her guard**, or when She addressed Herself in vocal prayer to the Lord. For in regard to interaction with God, the Author of speech, and with the holy angels, his messengers, when they treated in a visible manner with Her, this reason for maintaining silence did not hold good: on the contrary it was befitting, that, since there was no impediment, She should pray with her lips and her tongue; for it would not be proper to keep them unemployed for so long a time. - **Her Childhood Years**
>
> She invited her own angels to help Her to return proper thanks, and in union with them She alternated new songs of praise. Then She asked the same favor of the rest of the angels and saints in heaven; but during all this time the divine love so inflamed Her, that the Lord was obliged to strengthen Her, lest all her natural forces be consumed and death ensue. - **Her Devotion to the Passion of Christ and to the Holy Eucharist-HowShe Celebrated the Immaculate Conception and other Feasts**
>
> **For this purpose the most blessed Trinity despatched the archangel Gabriel with many others of the celestial hierarchies, who should announce to the Queen when and how her mortal life should come to an end and pass over into the eternal.**
>
> The devout Queen resolved to take leave of the holy places before her departure into heaven, and having obtained the consent of saint John **She left the house with him and with the thousand angels of her guard. Although these sovereign princes had always served and accompanied Her in all her errands, occupations and journeys, without having absented themselves for one moment since the instant of her birth**; yet on this occasion they manifested themselves to Her with greater beauty and refulgence, as if they felt special joy in seeing themselves already at the beginning of her last journey into heaven. The heavenly Princess, setting aside human occupations in order to enter upon her journey to the real and true fatherland, visited all the memorable places of our Redemption, marking each with the sweet abundance of her tears, recalling the sorrowful memories of what her Son there suffered, and fervently renewing its effects by most fervent acts of love, clamors and petitions for all the faithful, who should devoutly and reverently visit these holy places during the future ages of the Church. On Calvary She remained a longer time, asking of her divine Son the full effects of his redeeming Death for all the multitudes of souls there snatched from destruction. The ardor of her ineffable charity during this prayer rose to such a pitch, that it would have destroyed her life, if it had not been sustained by divine power. - **Saint Gabriel brings notice of Death**

The original unabridged Spanish edition has a whole chapter (23) dedicated to ***De las divisas con que los Santos Ángeles de guarda de María Santí- sima se le manifestaban, y de sus perfecciones***. In can be read here: [**Mistica Ciudad de Dios**](http://www.amen-etm.org/MisticaCiudaddeDios.pdf)

St. Micheal the Archangel seem a good choice as one of Mary’s Guardian Angels.

> *According to tradition, it was the holy archangel who led the Virgin Mary to heaven during her Assumption.*
>
> While little is known about the nature of the Virgin Mary’s Assumption into heaven, various traditions have been passed down over the centuries that relate the historical event and reflect on what could have happened.
>
> For example, there are many different traditions, both from the East and West, that state St. Michael the Archangel was the principal angel in charge of leading the body and soul of Mary into heaven.
>
> This is an ancient tradition, in accord with a belief that St. Michael was the angel who weighed the deeds of a deceased person and led them into eternal life. For this reason St. Michael is frequently depicted in statues or paintings holding scales. The liturgy of the Church appears to confirm this role of St. Michael with the following offertory chant said during a Requiem Mass.
>
> > O Lord Jesus Christ, King of glory,deliver the souls of all the faithful departed … let the standard-bearer holy Michaellead them into that holy light.
>
> A medieval text known as the Golden Legend relates an encounter Mary had with an angel prior to her death, preparing her for her assumption.
>
> > Then behold, an angel stood before her amid a great light and greeted her reverently as the mother of his Lord. “Hail, blessed Mary!” he said, “receive the blessing of him who bestowed salvation on Jacob. See, Lady, I have brought you a palm branch from paradise, and you are to have it carried before your bier. Three days from now you will be assumed from the body, because your Son is waiting for you, his venerable mother.”
>
> The angel’s name is not immediately revealed, but later on when Mary “died,” Jesus comes into the narrative and gives instructions to the holy archangel.
>
> Christ nodded his consent and immediately Michael the archangel came forward and presented Mary’s soul before the Lord. Then the Savior spoke and said: “Arise, my dear one, my dove, tabernacle of glory, vessel of life, heavenly temple! As you never knew the stain of sin through carnal intercourse, so you shall never suffer dissolution of the flesh in the tomb.” Thereupon Mary’s soul entered her body, and she came forth glorious from the monument and was assumed into the heavenly bridal chamber, a great multitude of angels keeping her company.
> While these legendary stories likely have no historical basis, they do provide for us a piece of meditation and invite us to consider how the Virgin Mary was welcomed into heaven by her Son and a company of angels. In particular, it would make sense for the “Prince of All Angels” to be at the forefront of those who welcomed the “Queen of Angels” into heaven. - [How St. Michael the Archangel led the Blessed Virgin Mary to heaven](https://aleteia.org/2018/08/15/how-st-michael-the-archangel-led-the-blessed-virgin-mary-to-heaven/)

The following may be of interest to some:

- [Is the Angel of Portugal Actually Saint Michael the Archangel?](https://www.ncregister.com/blog/angel-of-portugal)

Comment: The source does not says, the angels are guardian angels of Mary. She was born pure and not under slavery to sin, like Adam and Eve, She does not need any guardian angel. But angels encamp on Her because She is the chosen Woman destined to become the Mother of God, and those angels encamping around Mary are adoring Jesus the God-Man in Her pure womb.

Comment: @jongricafort Guardian Angels are appointed at birth. So the pregnancy of Mary does not follow your logic! Ultimately, Mary could have said no, but she did not to her **”fiat”**!

Comment: The meaning of guardian is only applicable to a fallen creature. Fallen man needs guardian because they are slave to Satan. While Mary was born with perennial enmity with Satan, to say that She need a guardian means, there will come a time that She will be conquered. The enmity is absolute. Genesis3:15

Comment: @jongricafort Formulate a question and post it, on the site, if you wish,  I am not going to debate this here . I guess St. Joseph, St. John the Baptist or the Prophet Elijah do not count?

Comment: Every soul receives a guardian angel, but St. Michael and St. Gabriel could not (Strictly) be Mary's guardian angels because guardianship belongs only to the lowest order of Angels

Comment: @eques True, but God could make exceptions to the rule due to the majestic dignity of Mary, as truly befitting  her station in life.

Comment: @KenGraham that is at best a vague speculation. I do recall some vague pious belief that Christ had St. Michael as his guardian (Which actually conflicts with the Thomistic idea that it's unfitting for Christ as God to have an angel guardian). Furthermore, the reason why Aquinas indicates that guardians are only of the lowest would tend to exclude even as "special" ministry the use of an archangel. Lastly, no two angels are equal even within the same order, so the highest of the angels could be Mary's guardian perhaps

Answer (score -2):

**Who was the Blessed Virgin Mary's guardian angel?**

Mary has no guardian angel, She doesn't need one, because She was immaculately conceived and born sinless and not a fallen creature.

Source: [Catechism of the Catholic Church](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p122a3p2.htm)

There was no teaching in the Catechism of the Catholic Church that says Mary has a guardian angel.

Adam & Eve was born pure with Holy image of God imprinted on their soul, same like Mary, She was born pure.

In the Book of Genesis, there was no mention of guardian angel protecting Adam & Eve. God had given them purity and graces to defend themselves from Satan.

Likewise, Mary being born pure, free of any stain of original sin, do not need a guardian angel.

This can be seen from God the Father holy decree in Genesis3:15. God the Father was the one who declare war with Satan and God the Father had chosen the Woman to fight Satan and crush his ugly proud head and not any guardian angels. God the Father did not said. don't worry in the battle with the serpent, the Woman guardian angel will protect you and be the one to crush the head of the old serpent.

> **I will put enmities between thee and the woman, and thy seed and her seed: she shall crush thy head, and thou shalt lie in wait for her heel.** - Genesis 3:15 DRA

Only a fallen creature, needs guardian angel because they are captured souls, they are the slaves of Satan.

In Catholic teachings, all mankind are born with original sin, and even after receiving the Sacrament of Baptism, the stain of original sin remains. Baptized soul, are still subject to Satan control. As St.Paul says:

> Did the good, then, become death for me? Of course not! Sin, in order that it might be shown to be sin, worked death in me through the good, so that sin might become sinful beyond measure through the commandment.

> We know that the law is spiritual; but I am carnal, sold into slavery to sin.

> What I do, I do not understand. For I do not do what I want, but I do what I hate.

> Now if I do what I do not want, I concur that the law is good.

> So now it is no longer I who do it, but sin that dwells in me.

> For I know that good does not dwell in me, that is, in my flesh. The willing is ready at hand, but doing the good is not.

> For I do not do the good I want, but I do the evil I do not want.

> Now if [I] do what I do not want, it is no longer I who do it, but sin that dwells in me.

> So, then, I discover the principle that when I want to do right, evil is at hand.

> For I take delight in the law of God, in my inner self,

> But I see in my members another principle at war with the law of my mind, taking me captive to the law of sin that dwells in my members.*

> Miserable one that I am! Who will deliver me from this mortal body?

> Thanks be to God through Jesus Christ our Lord. Therefore, I myself, with my mind, serve the law of God but, with my flesh, the law of sin.

We can see from the teachings of St.Paul and from the story of Adam & Eve in Genesis. The guardian angel was given to all fallen man, because of the fallen nature of man was a slave to sin and even a baptized soul did not attain purity due to stain of original sin, still exist in their soul.

> According to Catholic theologians or mystics, who was the Blessed Virgin Mary's guardian angel? St. Gabriel the Archangel?

Mary is superior to all guardian angels combined, even higher than Archangel Gabriel who was the nearest angel to the Throne of God, as shown in the Gospel of Luke, Archangel Gabriel bow down to Mary. Mary doesn't need a guardian angel because Satan and his demons are subject to her. Why? **She is the Queen of all Angels including the fallen angels.**

[Queen of Angels (The Catholic Thing)](https://www.thecatholicthing.org/2017/06/10/queen-of-angels/)

Comment: Is there a source of teaching in the Catechism of the Catholic Church that clearly says Mary did not have a guardian angel or that **”She is the Queen of all Angels including the fallen angels”**.

Comment: Jesus is the New Adam and Mary is the New Eve, this is a Catholic Church teaching. Adam & Eve was not given a guardian angel before the fall because they are pure or not corrupted or slave of Satan. Mary is pure and not a fallen creature, She doesnt need a guardian angel, If there are explicit teachings on guardian angel of Mary, then Geremia wont even ask this question. So, we need to look at the New Adam & New Eve analogy.

Comment: To state that **”In Catholic teachings, all mankind are born with original sin, and even after receiving the Sacrament of Baptism, the stain of original sin remains,”** is false, heretical and contrary to solid Catholic teachings. Baptism removes all stain of original sin. However we are left the inclinations towards sin our whole lives long. [Baptism Removes Our Toughest Stains](https://www.stclementromeo.org/baptism-removes-our-toughest-stains/).

Comment: Is concupiscence not a stain of original sin? Does baptism remove concupiscence?

Comment: No: Concupiscence is not a stain of original sin.  It is a result of the stain of original sin. **”As a result of original sin, human nature is weakened in its powers, subject to ignorance, suffering and the domination of death, and inclined to sin (this inclination is called "concupiscence").”** [CCC 418](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s2c1p7.htm)

Comment: Geremia  did not state **”if”** but **”who”** was the Guardian Angel of Mary!

Comment: This assumes that angel guardians are given exclusively because souls are capable of and have sinned, which is not the universal teaching of the Church. Jerome as cited by Aquinas indicates that every soul has an angel appointed to guard it. Aquinas does explain that Christ doesn't have a guardian angel but it's not because he is sinless but because he is guided by the Word of God, a distinction which can apply only to Him

Comment: Remember Council of Trent exclude Mary from their definition of original sin. Adam & Eve was not given a guardian angel because their purity & grace is sufficient to fight Satan deception. Jesus doesn't need a guardian angel because He was "entrusted" to the care and protection of Mary the chosen Woman who will crush Satan and St.Joseph the "terror of demons". Angels encamps around them because they adore the Incarnated Logos. That's why Satan was puzzled at Mary & Jesus having no guardian angels.

Comment: @jongricafort "given a guardian angel because their purity " does the Church teach that guardian angels are given because man is fallen?  "That's why Satan was puzzled at Mary & Jesus having no guardian angels" WHERE IS THAT FROM?